# Admin Ajax 413 Error - Max size is Higher

Tags: wordpress, admin-ajax

I have a plugin which performs admin ajax request on clicking send button in page. The data send some html data to PHP function. When i click send button, i receive the following error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413 ()

I have googled this and could find no solution.

Here are some more details to debug.

> Server info:      Apache
>
> PHP version:      7.3.16
>
> PHP post max size:        32 MB
>
> PHP time limit:       30
>
> PHP max input vars:       5000
>
> cURL version:     7.29.0, NSS/3.44
>
> MySQL version:        5.5.64-MariaDB
>
> Max upload size:      32 MB

Comment: which plugin do you use?

Comment: Custom plugin to perform some option table update

Comment: have you tried with increasing value of Max upload size, PHP post max size?

Comment: No i haven't tried that because the size is already set to 32MB. I am sure that the data send via ajax is nowhere near to 32MB

Comment: Yes, but it looks like an error 413 is a large file error in WordPress. Just try with that, after you can do the same as before.